# Pegging Quadruple (Four of a Kind) After Go

Tags: cribbage

Does a quadruple pegged after a "go" count for 12 points?  My neighbor and I had this unusual situation and we're not sure if we scored it correctly.

Player A led with a 10.
Player B played a 5 and pegged two points for the 15 combo.
Player A played a 5 and pegged two points for the pair (20 cumulative pts.).
Player B played another 5 and pegged six points for the three of a kind (25 cumulative pts.).

So far so good.  The next part is where we're confused.
Player A then called "go."
Player B played the fourth 5 and pegged 12 points for the quadruple, plus a point for the "go."

Is that correct?  Does player B get six points for the three of a kind then an additional 12 for the quadruple?  Is that a kind of double counting?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Yes: the "go" isn't a go until neither player can play another card to the current running count.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it (and as I've seen it scored in two different online Cribbage game sites) *whatever* score is due from cards played after "Go" is scored in addition to anything scored with the card that prompted the "Go".

Got a 4-run totaling 27, and a "Go"?  If you can play the fifth card in the run, you get the 5, plus either one for last card or two for 31 (as appropriate).  Same for 3 and 4 of a kind.